# Android Idea test error message: Unable to attach test reporter to test framework android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, test-framework

I'm trying to test an Android app following the instructions here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/testing-android-applications.html

and here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html

When I run the test it says  "Instantiating Tests" for a while, then it says "Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly."

The emulator starts OK, but nothing shows up on it's screen.

The console says:

```
Testing started at 11:41 AM ...
Waiting for device.
C:\Android\tools\emulator.exe -avd GoogleAPI_2_3_3 -netspeed full -netdelay none

Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is online: emulator-5554
Target device: emulator-5554 (GoogleAPI_2_3_3)


Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\<omitted details>.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mycompany
Installing com.mycompany
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mycompany"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.mycompany
Success


Running testsTest running startedFinish
```

Logcat doesn't seem to have anything helpful.  In particular it does not show the Log.d messages I put in my test.

Interestingly enough someone else asked about this problem on the Intellij developer community forum:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5363961#5363961

But the question has not been answered for several months.

Anyone have any ideas for diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-76259), it happens if you have no test methods. Define at least one test method to fix it.

Comment: So much for taking thins one step at a time (sigh).   Problem solved.

Comment: IDEA support usually answers within one hour -  providing correct answers

Comment: What do you mean create at least one test method? Having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: Just write a test method in your test class, don't run empty test class. If the issue remains, please contact support with a sample project.